# Insert points into a 2d grid

Tags: satellites, python, modis

I have a list of single point values that I want to insert into a grid.

point_values = [1, 4, 5, ...]

point_lats = [-12.101, -12.1023, -12.1031, ...]

point_lons = [155.511, 155.520, 155.533, ...]

the grid latitudes and longitudes are currently in 2d arrays of 2030 x 1350

latitudes = array of shape 2030 x 1350 of latitudes

longitudes = array of shape 2030 x 1350 of longitudes

how could I insert the points into the 2D grid if a point falls within the grid boundaries?

Comment: This looks more like a programming question (belonging on [SO]) but is currently very unclear. What do these arrays represent? What grid boundaries are you talking about?

Comment: this is to match up satellite observations from a lidar (calipso) to MODIS data. i would think this is earth science considering i'm doing it to observe earth processes.

Comment: Although this question is about remote sensing, you likely will get helpful answers from Geographic Information Systems stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this is a mathematical modelling problem. You just happen to be using earth science data - satellite LIDAR readings.

Ore reserve geologists constantly deal with this, but in three dimensions when they are required to create a block models of a geological deposit from drill hole data.

Scientific fields that use 2D data would include: forestry, meteorology and ground contamination studies looking into pollution effects of smelters.

Methods you need to consider are [Inverse Distance Weighting](https://gisgeography.com/inverse-distance-weighting-idw-interpolation/) and possibly [variography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram) and [kriging](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/how-kriging-works.htm). Variography and kriging are elements of [geostatistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/what-is-geostatistics-.htm), also known as the [Theory of Regionalized Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regionalized_variable_theory).

With inverse distance weighting, the distance variable is usually raised to a power n, i.e. ${1/d^n}$. Choosing the appropriate value of $n$ is the tricky part. When geologists used inverse distance weighting, prior to primary using geostatistics, typically the value of $n$ used was 2, but values between 1 and 3 have been used for different deposits.

Given that you are using two dimension data, you may need to use [GIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) software or other modelling software that offers grid interpolation methods, such as I have mentioned to achieve what you want.